# Jenkins + SVN + PKCS12 + HTTPS

Tags: svn, https, hudson, jenkins, pkcs#12

There is a problem with the usage of SVN + PKCS12 + HTTPS. When I want to add an SVN repository to a Jenkins Template, I get an error.
It seems that the SVN Client does not support this way of authentication.
First I checked on a Debian workstation, with Jenkins 1.467, whether this would work and it did. I used the same certificate for this.
Second, I tried the same and other versions of Jenkins on my server without any result.
Now the question: I this a bug in Jenkins, or am I totally doing something wrong?

```
Environment:
Ubuntu 12.04 Server
Jenkins 1.478
```

Stacktrace:

```
Aug 28, 2012 2:35:19 PM hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl doCheckRemote
INFO: Failed to access subversion repository https://<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>/trunk
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: OPTIONS /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/trunk failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:300)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:289)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:277)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:696)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:619)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:103)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1018)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:99)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.checkRepositoryPath(SubversionSCM.java:2067)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doCheckRemote(SubversionSCM.java:2001)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:488)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:162)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
        at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:173)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:63)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
        at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:215)
        at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: No credential to try. Authentication failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:37)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:32)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:185)
        at hudson.scm.FilterSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(FilterSVNAuthenticationManager.java:35)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPSSLKeyManager.initialize(HTTPSSLKeyManager.java:423)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPSSLKeyManager.initializeNoException(HTTPSSLKeyManager.java:406)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPSSLKeyManager.chooseClientAlias(HTTPSSLKeyManager.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractWrapper.chooseClientAlias(SSLContextImpl.java:282)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:629)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:228)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:609)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:545)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:945)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1190)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:657)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:108)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.sendData(HTTPConnection.java:238)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:168)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:385)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:298)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: svn: E200015: No credential to try. Authentication failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
        ... 101 more
Aug 28, 2012 2:35:19 PM hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl doCheckRevisionPropertiesSupported
INFO: Failed to access subversion repository https://<subxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>/trunk
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: OPTIONS /sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/trunk failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:300)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:289)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:277)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:696)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:619)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:103)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1018)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:99)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.checkRepositoryPath(SubversionSCM.java:2067)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doCheckRevisionPropertiesSupported(SubversionSCM.java:2202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:488)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:162)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
        at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:173)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:63)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
        at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:215)
        at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: No credential to try. Authentication failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:37)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:32)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:185)
        at hudson.scm.FilterSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(FilterSVNAuthenticationManager.java:35)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPSSLKeyManager.initialize(HTTPSSLKeyManager.java:423)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPSSLKeyManager.initializeNoException(HTTPSSLKeyManager.java:406)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPSSLKeyManager.chooseClientAlias(HTTPSSLKeyManager.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractWrapper.chooseClientAlias(SSLContextImpl.java:282)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:629)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:228)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:609)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:545)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:945)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1190)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:657)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:108)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.sendData(HTTPConnection.java:238)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:168)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:385)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:298)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: svn: E200015: No credential to try. Authentication failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
        ... 101 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem...

On my Ubuntu 12.04 distribution, OpenJDK was used by Jenkins by default.
Now I installed Oracle Java (manual here: http://www.devsniper.com/ubuntu-12-04-install-sun-jdk-6-7/ ).
When using self signed certificates, here is a manual that helps A LOT to get through the struggle of adding SSCs in your Java Keystore: http://www.erikzaadi.com/2011/09/09/connecting-jenkins-to-self-signed-certificated-servers/

I hope for other people that this will help!!